# Is there a way to setup a getter in redux toolkit store?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

For example, I have:

productPrice: 120, productQuantity: 2, and I want totalProductPrice to be productPrice * productQuantity.

Is it possible to set it up in initialState of a slice with the redux toolkit?

I tried it like this:

```
get totalProductPrice() {
  return this.productPrice * this.productQuantity;
}
```

Comment: Hey there so your message is a bit unclear are you statically setting product price and product quantity ? 

Other wise could you please include the file with your initialState and your reduxSlice in so that it can be a bit more clear

If your not statically setting the values you would then need to have a reducer that updates the totalProductPrice

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That would not be a getter, but in Redux just a `selector`.

```js
const selectTotalProductPrice = state => state.mySlice.productPrice * state.mySlice.productQuantity
```

and in your component

```js
const totalProductPrice = useSelector(selectTotalProductPrice )
```

If that calculation is more expensive, you should be using a memoized selector. You can read up on those in the documentation under [Computing Derived Data](https://redux.js.org/recipes/computing-derived-data).